# Can you do website manipulation with javascript or actionscript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, authentication, actionscript

Using javascript or flash, is it possible to log into websites and than pull content from that page?

I am trying to make a phone app that displays content from a site that requires log in.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that this is possible, it's almost certainly not a good idea.  Your phone app then has brittle dependencies on the structure of the site from which you're pulling data, and you have no way except notification of failure to detect when those dependencies change.

Does the site from which you want to pull information provide an API? That would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes, though depending on the browser, it may not allow cross-site scripting.  The only way I can think of on a mobile site to do this is either with an ajax call to submit login credentials and grab data, or with an iframe.  iframe would probably work better since  ajax calls would probably not set the right cookies for session id maintenance.  I dont know how elegant this solution would be.